Upgrading TypeScript 5.6.2 to 5.7.1-rc causes RCL to not build - node.exe exited with code 1
I am new to TypeScript/JS and was able to successfully use version 5.6.2 in my Blazor Server RCL. I upgraded to version 5.7.1-rc and the RCL won't compile.
Not sure what I need to do to get this working?
I am using VS Version 17.13.0 Preview 1.0 with a .NET 9.0  Aspire Blazor Web Application
